# How can I clone data in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I need to get store data (clean data), and modified data. Im try to do this like this:

```
mounted() {
 this.newdata = this.storedata;
}
```

But when i change this.newdata, storedata will changing to autmatically. How i can prevent that? I need for storedata cant be changed. In storedata has callbacks, not only props.

Comment: Object with many props and callbacks (like list: [{callback: this.itemChanger, id: 45}])

Comment: Your title implies you don't want to clone the original, but your question implies you don't want to change the original.  It can't be both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `storedata` is an Array or Object or Array of object, you can use a library from [Lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash).
It will clone your entire `storedata` to new varibale and any changes in `newData` won't affect to `storedata`.

```js
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
export default {
  mounted() {
   this.newdata = _.cloneDeep(this.storedata)
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if `storedata` is ***array***

```
 this.newdata = [ ...this.storedata ];
```

if `storedata` is ***json***

```
 this.newdata = { ...this.storedata };
```

if `storedata` is ***string***

```
 this.newdata = this.storedata.slice();
```

Comment: i dont understand how it helps me?

Comment: seems like your storedata is the array, so refer to  this.newdata = [ ...this.storedata ];

Comment: Primitives (`string` included) are not passed by reference. They're passed by value. Which means a copy of a string will ***never*** reference the original string and will ***always*** create a new one with the same value. So slice is not necessary for strings. Also, note spreading only clones the top level but any deeper nested property holding a reference (an array or object) will point to the same reference in both original and clone.

Answer (score 0):

For **shallow** copy [1-level deep] you can use the spread operator like this
 `this.newdata = [ ...this.storedata ];`

If you want to clone a deep nested array then you can use cloneDeep from lodash

```
yarn add lodash.cloneDeep
```

and this is how you use it

```
<script>
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.cloneDeep'
export default {
  mounted() {
   this.newdata = cloneDeep(this.storedata)
  }

}
</script>
```

Both of the above methods will help you to create a clean array using a new reference